# c++のテンプレートで特定の型を要素に持ったコンテナ型だけ受けたい

Tags: c++, templates

c++のテンプレートで

```
template<class T>
void print(T &&iterable)
{
for(auto && str : iterable)
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

のような関数テンプレートを作ってテンプレートクラスTにはstd::stringを要素に持ったstd::vectorやstd::dequeなどのようなcontainerクラスだけを受け取るようにしたいのですがどのように書けばよいでしょうか？

```
template<class T>
void print(T<std::string> &&iterable)
{
for(auto && str : iterable)
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
std::vector<std::string>a({"1","2","3"});
print<std::vector>(a);
```

のように書いたらコンパイルエラーで通りませんでした。

Comment: 指摘を受けたので追記。実際は中で全然違う処理をしようと思っているので、関数定義の中で明示するのではなく、エディタ等の解析の恩恵を受けられるように引数を受ける段階ではじけるようにしたいです。

Comment: コメント欄に追記しても表示順位が上がらないので、質問欄に追記した方が良いでしょう。`c++ "template parameters"` 等で検索すれば解るかと思いますが、例えば `template <template <class T, class = std::allocator<T> > class C>`, `void print(C<std::string> &iterable)` とします。

Comment: 「エディタ等の解析の恩恵」というのは、具体的にどのようなサポートを期待していますか？一般的なエディタはC++テンプレートの深い解析まではしない／できないことが多く、エディタのためにという理由は実効的な意義が微妙かもしれません。特定のエディタ／ツール想定があれば、本文中に明記されたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。template templateという書き方があることがわかったので一応解決しました。

Comment: @UNLIMITED 質問は後からでも「編集」できますので、前提条件など重要な情報はコメント欄ではなく質問文への追記をお願いします。また、回答によって解決した場合には、役立った回答を「承認済み」でチェックしてあげてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

明示的に`std::string`だけを受け取るのではだめなんでしょうか？

```
template<class T>
void print(T&& iterable) {
    for (std::string&& str : iterable)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

> エディタ等の解析の恩恵を受けられるように引数を受ける段階ではじけるようにしたい

各エディタの解析処理依存なので明確に回答しようがないです。一例としては

```
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename T::value_type, std::string>>>
void print(T &&iterable) {
    for (auto && str : iterable)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

のように[`std::enable_if`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/type_traits/enable_if.html)を使用して有効となる条件を指定することもできます。

> template templateという書き方があることがわかったので一応解決しました。

もちろんある程度はtemplate templateで解決可能ですが、２番目のtemplate引数が`std::array`のように数値であったり、`std::stack`（コンテナとは呼べない？）のようにコンテナだったりとバラバラなので、一般的には解決できないかと思います。（質問者の要件は満たせたかもしれないが、質問文の要件は満たすことができない回答不能問題です。）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。実際は中で全然違う処理をしようと思っているのでそのような形で関数定義の中で明示するのではなく引数で受ける段階で受けられないようにはじきたいんです。エディタ等の解析の恩恵を受けられるように。

Comment: @UNLIMITED そのような意図であれば、質問文に明示していただけますでしょうか

Comment: 確かにそうするべきでした。申し訳ないです...